# How to use Rails number_to_currency options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I'm using Rails and wanted to convert a float to currency. I'm using `number_to_currency` in a Sidekiq Worker, so I've added `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in the file and where I want the conversion I've added the following:

```
number_to_currency(value, unit: '', delimeter: '.', separator: ',')
```

And I wanted the result something like: `1.200,09` but its not working. An example of values I have and want to convert is: `1001.4290000000004` which should be converted to `1.001,43`. I've also tried:

```
number_to_currency(final_total, unit: '', delimeter: ',', separator: '.')
```

And still doesn't work. I'm getting is  `1,200.09`. I'm using Rails 4.2.x

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo in word `delimiter`. It should be as follows:

```
number_to_currency(value, unit: '', delimiter: '.', separator: ',')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want get result like this `1001.4290000000004 => 1,001.43`, you can use this method:

```
number_with_delimiter(value , delimiter: ",", separator: ".")
```

But befor u need convert `value` to the desired value:

```
value = 1001.4290000000004.round(2) #=> 1001.43
```